# Can I sent file via Air Drop from my app?

Tags: ios7, airdrop

I have two iPhone 4S. I want to sent file from one device to another device through my application using Air drop. Actually I want to know can I implement Air drop in my application for file transfer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the [AirDrop sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html) to learn how to add support to an app. Unfortunately the 4S does not support AirDrop (see this [kb](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5887) for more details)

Comment: your most welcome! please mark my answer as the correct one if you find it the most helpful!